# Помогите разобраться с работой intrinsic функций в коде

Tags: c++, распараллеливание, векторы, sse

На просторах интернета нашел реализацию клеточного автомата игра "Жизнь", ускоренную использованием intrinsic функций. Не могу понять что делает данный отрывок кода

```
void gameoflife8vec(uint8_t *counts, uint8_t *states, size_t width,
    size_t height) {
    assert(width % (sizeof(__m256i)) == 0);
    size_t awidth = width + 2;
    computecounts8vec(counts, states, width, height);
    __m256i shufmask =
        _mm256_set_epi8(
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
        );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; j += sizeof(__m256i)) {
            __m256i c = _mm256_lddqu_si256(
                (const __m256i *)(counts + (i + 1) * awidth + j + 1));
            c = _mm256_subs_epu8(
                c, _mm256_set1_epi8(
                    1)); // max was 8 = 0b1000, make it 7, 1 becomes 0, 0 remains 0

            __m256i oldstate = _mm256_lddqu_si256(
                (const __m256i *)(states + (i + 1) * awidth + j + 1));
            __m256i newstate = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(
                shufmask, _mm256_or_si256(c, _mm256_slli_epi16(oldstate, 3)));
            _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)(states + (i + 1) * awidth + (j + 1)),
                newstate);
        }
    }
}
```

точнее не понимаю что конкретно и как делает вот эта строчка

```
__m256i newstate = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(shufmask, _mm256_or_si256(c, _mm256_slli_epi16(oldstate, 3)));
```

В данной реализации *states* это массив состояний клеток ("Мир", то есть в нем записывается жив / мертв), *counts* это массив в котором записано количество живых соседей для аналогичной клетки из *states*. Количество живых соседей для всех клеток из *states* считает функция *computecounts8vec*. То есть получается, что вышеупомянутая строчка должна, проверив правила игры (если клетка жива и у нее < 2 или > 3 соседей, она умирает или, если мертва и жизых соседей 3, то она оживает) получить новое состояние для вектора клеток из *states*. Я погуглив выяснил, что порядок действий в строчке таков:

1) произвести побитовый сдвиг на 3 бита влево всех состояний в векторе *oldstate*

2) получить результат операции побитовое ИЛИ для *c*, которое является количеством живых соседей - 1, и результатом пункта 1)

3) перемешать результат пункта 2) согласно маске *shufmask* (крайне неясно откуда такая маска)

Возможно я неправильно понял смысл работы функций, но не **могу понять как происходит магия в этой строчке и, в общем, что происходит с длинами упакованных в векторы чисел**. Объясните, пожалуйста, мне глупому, желательно максимально подробно, что, куда и заччем.

Память под *states* и *counts* выделяется следующим образом:

```
uint8_t *states = (uint8_t *)malloc((N + 2) * (N + 2) * sizeof(uint8_t));
uint8_t *counts = (uint8_t *)malloc((N + 2) * (N + 2) * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Где N - размер матрицы (Мир игры) в одном измерении.

P.S. первоисточник кода https://github.com/lemire/SIMDgameoflife

Comment: А [это](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524017) и [это](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb) смотрели?

Comment: @MBo к сожалению, да и все равно не понимаю как получается новое состояние клетки. То есть побитовый сдвиг мне понятен(пока непонятно зачем он и почему там epi16 не смотря на то что используются 8 битовые *uint8_t*), побитовое или, опятьже ясно как работает, но не ясна цель, и шафл уже совсем дебри

Comment: Наверное нужно смотреть на  код  до определения функции...

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan добавил первоисточник кода

Comment: Извените, как то нерезонно разбираться в чужом плохом(не ООП) коде , а потом рассказывать вам  о нем. Я говорил, что вам самим нужно смотреть и разобраться, если вам это интересно

Comment: @lolmosk, идея shuffle в том, что i-ый элемент второго операнда задает, какой элемент первого  надо поместить в i-ый элемент результата. Т.е. **результат  образуется из shufmask**. / Почему, в соответствии с правилами игры, он (второй операнд) делается таким образом, это и есть суть вашего вопроса (в этом я не разбирался)